# How to delete parent directories without deleting its children directories in git?

Tags: git

I have a git repository that has the file structure of /react-projects/programming-todo-list/programming-todo-list/*

I want to delete the upper directories /react-projects/programming-todo-list so that it ends up looking like this : programming-todo-list/*

Is there a way to delete the upper directories without deleting the children directories?

Comment: Start with `git mv`?

Comment: You first want to move the target directory to where you want. Then you may delete the former parent directory

Comment: @KoreyLombardi Great! What command did you used? git mv?

Comment: Yes, I used mv ../..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git mv programming-todo-list ../..` is enough if you don't want to impact your past commits (which would still display `programming-todo-list` in its former place).

If you can rewrite the history of your repository, then [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) (Python-based, to be [installed first](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md)) is the right tool, using [path-based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
git filter-repo --path-rename react-projects/programming-todo-list/programming-todo-list:programming-todo-list
```